# Monterey changes my desktop background when I plug in external displays

Tags: display, thunderbolt, dock, desktop, thunderbolt-display

I have a MacBook Pro (i5, 2020ish, two Thunderbolt ports, Big Sur), a CalDigit Thunderbolt3 dock, an Apple Thunderbolt display (plugged into the dock via an Apple-branded Thunderbolt 3-to-Thunderbolt2 adapter) and an LG 32" Ultrawide display (attached to the CalDigit dock via DisplayPort).

I have all three displays set to different wallpapers (currently, I have the Big Sur dynamic stylized images on them, but I've reproduced this with static images or with plain color desktops).

When I unplug from the CalDigit dock, I sometimes (but not always) see the Retina display's wallpaper change to the Monterey abstract canyon.  It will set to the appropriate time of day as if it were the dynamic wallpaper, but it won't change on its own.

This same thing will happen almost any time I plug the MacBook into the CalDigit dock, but it will affect different displays.  It's always one and only one display, the other two show the expected wallpaper.  And again, it isn't dynamic.  E.g. if I plug in at 5:30 AM, one of the displays will get the "dark" canyon image, but it doesn't change with the time, even though the other two displays update their images as expected.

After experimenting with this a bit, trying to nail down the reproducer, I changed my dynamic desktop pictures to solid colors, and still one of the displays changed to the Canyon wallpaper.  After changing my desktops back to the dynamic Big Sur images, unplugging and replugging resulted in one display changing to... a solid color - and a different color than I had used in the previous attempt.

One last oddity, when I go to the Desktop & Screensaver panel in System Preferences, the affected display tells me that it's currently displaying the wallpaper I had selected, even though it's actually showing the canyon image - BUT, in the case where it changed the display to the solid color, it accurately told me that it was set to "Red Orange".